# Making sense of Realm, Moya, and ObjectMapper

Tags: ios, swift, realm, objectmapper, moya

So I'm trying to make sense of how to use Realm, Moya, and ObjectMapper.

I use Moya to make requests to my API. I use Realm to keep the returned data in a local database. And I use ObjectMapper to map the JSON objects to correct Realm variable.

However, I've come to an issue now where I'm not sure how to decode the JSON response in order to put it through the mapper.

Here is my Moya code:

```
provider.request(.signIn(email: email, password: password)) { result in
    switch result {
    case let .success(response):
        do {
            // Get the response data
            let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyResponse.self, from: response.data)

            // Get the response status code
            let statusCode = response.statusCode

            // Check the status code
            if (statusCode == 200) {
                // Do stuff
            }
        } catch {
            print(error)
        }
    case let .failure(error):
        print(error)
        break
    }
}
```

The error happens on this line:

```
In argument type 'MyResponse.Type', 'MyResponse' does not conform to expected type 'Decodable'
```

The `MyResponse` class looks like this:

```
class MyResponse: Object, Mappable {
    @objc dynamic var success = false
    @objc dynamic var data: MyResponseData? = nil

    required convenience init?(map: Map) {
        self.init()
    }

    func mapping(map: Map) {

    }
}
```

I understand *why* I'm getting that error, I just don't know the correct way to solving it. Am I missing something in the documentation of one of the above frameworks? Am I doing this totally wrong? How should I fix my line of code?

---

I've tried @Kamran's solution, but I got the error:

> Argument labels '(JSON:)' do not match any available overloads

On the line:

```
let myResponse = MyResponse(JSON: json)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting that error because you are decoding using Swift JSONDecoder which requires you to implement Codable which wraps Encodable and Decodable (JSON <-> YourObject).

If you're using Swift 4 you can use Codable instead of relying on 3rd party libraries.

MyResponse would become:

```
class MyResponse: Codable {
    let success: Bool
    let data: MyResponseData? 
}
```

And MyResponseData should implement Codable too.

After this you should be able to do:

```
do {
    let data = try JSONDecoder().decode(MyResponse.self, from: response.data)
} catch let error { 
    // handle error
}
```